# Valid use of `componentWillMount`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Going through the React component lifecycle hooks I see [`componentWillMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount). Does anybody have a valid use case for it, something that cannot be done with an ES6 class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` acts, essentially, as the "constructor" hook if you're using `React.createClass`-based components instead of ES2015 class-based components. One notable thing about this lifecycle hook is that it's called during server rendering.